# Migrate Parse files to Google Cloud Storage

Tags: java, google-app-engine, servlets, parse-platform, google-cloud-storage

I am attempting to remove my app's dependency on Parse Backend since it will be discontinued.

I have begun to transfer everything over onto Google App Engine and the app is now working fine on there.

However, I still have some files hosted on Parse from when the app was being BETA tested.

I would like to get those files (.mp4 and .png) and move them over to Google Cloud Storage.

**I know how to upload/serve** files to Cloud Storage.

**I do not know how to upload files to Cloud Storage from a URL** hosted in a different location though.

```
    HTTPRequest request = new HTTPRequest(new URL(uploadURL), HTTPMethod.POST);
    request.setHeader(new HTTPHeader("Content-type", "multipart/form-data"));

    byte[] data = ?? how do I convert URL to byte array

    request.setPayload(data);

    HTTPResponse response = URLFetchServiceFactory.getURLFetchService().fetch(request);
```

Has anyone had success in uploading a file to GCS from a url in the cloud and not an actual file on their device?

---

I cannot use use the [Cloud Storage Transfer Service](https://cloud.google.com/storage/transfer/#urls) in the Developers Console to transfer files from URLs as this solution is a manual solution.

I need a solution that allows me to go through a large list (located on parse database) and update the entries in the App Engine Datastore after uploading the files to Cloud Storage.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Without using the [cloud storage transfer service](https://cloud.google.com/storage/transfer/#urls) I had to download the file from the url in order to upload it to GCS, and update the entity in the datastore.

So I can go 1 of 2 ways.

1) boot up a virtual machine using [Google Compute Engine](https://cloud.google.com/compute/) to download the file, reupload it to Google Cloud Storage, and update the file location for the entity in the Datastore.

or

2) Write some code for the iPhone Simulator to handle the downloading, uploading, and updating the entity in the datastore.

Option 2 was the cheaper option (possibly slower) but both should work.

Answer (score 1):

You could use the Cloud Storage Transfer Service in the Developers Console to transfer files from URLs:

https://cloud.google.com/storage/transfer/#urls

Comment: I did see this, however, it seems pretty manual. You have to create a hash and calculate the bytes for each entry. I have to update the entry in the datastore with the new Cloud Storage name after transferring the files which would take ages if I did every entry manually

Answer (score 0):

You can use something like this to stream the contents of a URL into a file in GCS using the [GCS Java Client](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/java/googlecloudstorageclient/) (you can do this locally to avoid using GAE resources):

```
GcsFilename fileName = new GcsFilename("MyBucket", "MyObject");
URL url = new URL("http://example.com/path/to/file");

GcsService gcsService = GcsServiceFactory.createGcsService(RetryParams.getDefaultInstance());

try {
  GcsOutputChannel outputChannel = gcsService.createOrReplace(fileName, GcsFileOptions.getDefaultInstance());
  ObjectOutputStream outputStream = new ObjectOutputStream(Channels.newOutputStream(outputChannel));
  InputStream inputStream = url.openStream();
  byte[] buffer = new byte[4096];  // Use any buffer size desired

  int bytesRead;
  while ((bytesRead = inputStream.read(buffer)) > 0) {
    outputStream.write(buffer, 0, bytesRead);
  }
  outputStream.close();
}
catch (IOException e) {
  e.printStackTrace ();
}
```

This is untested though, so some changes may be needed.

Comment: Did not work for me. posted an answer that explains why